# Noether's theorem for scale invariance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, noethers-theorem, scale-invariance

When we have the Lagrangian 
$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial _\mu \phi\partial^\mu \phi \tag{1} $$
We have a symmetry given by $$x^\mu\mapsto e^\alpha x^\mu, \qquad\phi\mapsto e^{-\alpha} \phi.\tag{2}$$ I'm struggling to find the Noether charge for this symmetry. The formula is 
$$j^\mu=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\delta\phi-k^\mu\tag{3}$$
where $$\delta \phi=-\phi \tag{4}$$ in this case, but I can't find $k^\mu$ such that $$\delta \mathcal {L}=\partial _\mu k^\mu .\tag{5}$$

Comment: Hint: The scale transformation has both vertical $\phi$ components & horizontal $x^{\mu}$ components. The horizontal contribution is missing in your Noether current formula.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270245/2451

Comment: What Qmechanic (probably) means by horizontal & vertical components is that your Eq. (3) is wrong: the transformation of $\phi(x)$ under (2) is $\phi(x) \to e^{-\alpha}\phi(e^\alpha x)
\approx \phi(x) + \alpha \left[ -\phi(x) + x^\mu \partial_\mu \phi(x) \right] + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^2)$,
i.e. $\delta\phi = - \phi + x^\mu \partial_\mu \phi$. You should be able to derive the Noether current from here.

Answer (score 2):

If u want to compute the Noether currents, u can do as follows:

$$x'^u=x^u+\delta x^u \quad \delta x^u=e^aE_a^u$$
   $$\phi'=\phi+\delta\phi \quad \delta\phi=e^aX_a$$
   $$J_a^u=[\eta_p^uL-\frac{dL}{dd_u\phi}d_p\phi]E_a^p+\frac{dL}{dd_u\phi}X_a$$

So in your case results:

$$E^u=x^u \quad X=-\phi$$
   $$J^u=\frac{1}{2}d_p\phi d^p\phi x^2-d_v\phi d^u\phi x^v-(d^u\phi)\phi$$
Using Euler-Lagrange equation $d_ud^u\phi=0$ it semplifies to

$$J^u=-d_v\phi d^u\phi x^v-(d^u\phi)\phi$$

that u can verify it is conserved

Comment: Wow to such badly wording (u instead of you) and badly formated equations!  $d$ instead of partial derivatives, $x^2$ and ugly tensorial indices ... are worth a -1 vote.

Comment: love you too @Cham